# show output of joined table in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

2 so i have two tables named usertype and user

The usertype table has this columns

- usertypeID
- usertype

The user has this columns

- userID
- userName
- usertypeID (foreign key from the usertype table)
- userdescription

i'am having troubles on how i could display the user table including their corresponding usertype.
i already have two different models for the usertype and user

here is my table for usertype

```
class userstype extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'dbo_systemtypes';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
```

}

and here is my users model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'dbo_systemusers';
/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
```

}

Comment: Use this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one

Answer (score 1):

Later, but maybe it will be useful for someone else.

To your User model add:

```
public function userType() {
    return $this->hasOne('UsersType', 'usertypeID');  // rename your userstype model to UsersType
}
```

Then you get all User attributes including usertype:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$name = $user->userName;
$description = $user->userDescription;
$userType = $user->userType->usertype;
                //    ^           ^
                //dyn.property   column
```

Or if you want only usertype:

```
$userType = User::find(1)->userType->usertype;
```